# 'molpaylibrary/molpaylib.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate MOLPay online payment gateway through its SDK.

When I import the MOLPay Library to `AppDelegate.m` and `ViewController.m` I get an error saying:

> 'molpaylibrary/molpaylib.h' file not found.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the MOLPay framework and integrated into a Xcode project. There is no problem reaching the header file.

see here:

git clone  https://github.com/andersc/MOLPay.git

Use that project and you should have no problem integrating MOLPay.

/A